# Dynamic hosting on Apache with two differently constructed URLs

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, virtualhost

I have created a CMS which uses the URL as the directory name - like this:

```
VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/html/%0
```

So, `www.somesite.com` is served from: `/var/www/html/www.somesite.com`

This works, but, I also need a sandbox URL because often the site URL will not be available at the time the site is being created.

So, in addition to routing the normal URL, I also need to route something like this to the directory:

```
www.myCMSThingy.com/somesite
```

Other CMSs must have solved this problem but I can’t seem to find any examples.

Comment: Why don't you use your own domain - and create subdomains/directories based off your projects?

Comment: That's what I want to do, but I need to find a way for both my domain and the customer's domain to resolve to the same place.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that you are running both in the **same linux server machine**

- *www.somesite.com* - VirtualDocumentRoot at `/var/www/html/www.somesite.com`
- *www.mycmsthingy.com* - VirtualDocumentRoot at `/var/www/html/www.mycmsthingy.com`

If that is true, you can symlink your VirtualDocumentRoot like this to get what you want:

```
cd /var/www/html

ln -s www.somesite.com  www.mycmsthingy.com/somesite
```

In the browser, `http://www.mycmsthingy.com/somesite/` will have the contents of your www.somesite.com

Comment: That's a brilliant idea.  Thanks.  I was tying myself in knots with Apache modules